# Deserializing JSON from local storage to Fabric JS object - JSON created from form data

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage, deserialization, fabricjs

I'm using Fabric js for a project I'm working on and encountering a few difficulties.  My aim is to allow a user to enter details into a form.  The form will then be turned into a JSON object and stored using local storage.

Upon pressing submit the user is taken to a new page where the JSON is retrieved and objects are created.

I'm having difficulty with the latter part.  Getting the information from the form into JSON is working fine, various tests show that the output is as it should be.

When creating the object there are problems, the object is showing on the canvas as a simple border with corners, it can be moved and selected but all other attributes such as size and colour are lost.  I think it's because of how the JSON is being deserilized.  I've searched for a solution but yet to find one, any help is hugely appreciated.

Sample code:

This is my test instance that creates an object as expected:

```
var a = {
    type: "rect",
    left:200,
    top:110,
    fill:'red',
    width:80,
    height:50
};
```

The same as above but from the local storage:

```
[Log] From JSON:    {"type":"rect","top":"110","left":"200","fill":"red","height":"50","width":"80"} (sim.html, line 135)
```

To get the data I'm using:

```
var test = localStorage.getItem("Number1");
console.log("From JSON: " +test);

var obj = JSON && JSON.parse(test) || $.parseJSON(test);
console.log(obj.type +"-"+ obj.left);
```

When a is added in the below method it works yet obj does not.  The main difference I can see if the quotations but I'm not sure if that is the issue and if so how to remove it simply.

Function to iterate over and render objects:

```
    fabric.util.enlivenObjects([circle1, obj], function(objects) {
    var origRenderOnAddRemove = canvas.renderOnAddRemove;
    canvas.renderOnAddRemove = false;

    objects.forEach(function(o) {
        canvas.add(o);
    });
    canvas.renderOnAddRemove = origRenderOnAddRemove;
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Your JSON does not look correct to me - the numbers are all strings.  How do you get the object *into* storage?

Comment: You should use `JSON.stringify( object )`. *edit* ah OK - well your saved object is **not** the same as that "a" object, because you're saving the form fields as strings and not numbers. I don't know whether that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: Yes sorry I updated that comment.

Comment: Well, form field values are always strings, so at some point the code is going to have to know which need to be turned into numbers. (Again, that's assuming that the number/string thing really is the problem.)  That conversion could happen when you serialize the form, or it could happen later.

Comment: Maybe you could modify the serializer code so that it could look for a "number" class on the input elements, and convert them at that point.

Comment: I'll add an answer with some ideas.

Comment: Why not use the jQuery `.serialize` against your form object before storing into local storage? http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: @KrisIvanov - I'd like it in JSON for flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can modify your "serialize" routine so that it converts appropriate inputs to numbers:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        var value = this.value || '';
        if (/^\d+$/.test(value))
          value = +value;

        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(value);
        } else {
            o[this.name] = value;
       }
    }} );
    return o;
};
```

That looks for input values that *look like* numbers and converts them. (It only looks for integers; if you wanted to also test for numbers with decimal fractions the regular expression could be modified.)

This isn't the most robust thing in the world, since it's making a fairly big assumption. To be more accurate you'd have to do something like tag your form inputs with a class to identify whether they're supposed to be treated as numeric, and then implement your own serializer to traverse all the inputs.

Comment: Brillinat!  Thanks Pointy!  Could you say why when I tried if(name == "bla"){do bla} it didn't work yet?  Does it evaluate strings differently?

Comment: @SteveGreen well no, I'm not entirely sure, though if you have some non-numeric fields then clearly you wouldn't want to convert those to numbers; you'd end up with `NaN`.  I tend to prefer conversion with `+` or the `Number` constructor because `parseInt` ignores garbage at the end of the string (though sometimes that may be desirable behavior).

Comment: I thought it was a bit odd too but put it down to not knowing enough about JS to make proper sense of it.  I was able to return the field name and then compared them but still nothing.  However, your solution works perfectly, than you so much for your time and help.  Now onto the next task - creating a tree of sorts form the form, this is just one entry, I now need multiple :D